# java.lang.unsatisfiedlinkerror:couldn't load testjni: findLibrary returned null

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I create an android project(TestJni) in the android source path **/packages/apps/** without eclipse. I had compiled the android source code.

I had added the **jni** folder . **Under the jni folder**, there are some files ,including Android.mk and basic.c .

Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := basic.c
LOCAL_MODULE := testjni
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

basic.c

```
#include<string.h>
#include<jni.h>
jstring Java_com_example_FristJniActivity_getStringFromJni(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz) {
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "hello ndk and jni");
}
```

root of current android Project, there is a Android.mk
Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under, src)
LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := TestJni
LOCAL_JNI_SHARD_LIBRARIES := testjni
LOCAL_REQUIRED_MODULES := testjni
include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)
```

in src folder,there is a activity(FristJniActivity)
FristJniActivity.java

```
static {
    System.loadLirary("testjni");
}
public native String getStringFromJni();

public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
    super.onCreate(b);
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText(getStringFromJNi());
    setContentView(tv);
}
```

Then I compile the TestJni app, and the apk can be found.But after I push it into the handset, **force close** .

The error is :
  java.lang.unsatisfiedlinkerror:couldn't load testjni: findLibrary returned null

I googled . But I can't find the solution.

I had checked the apk file, the testjni.so file is already exist in the /lib/armeabi-v7a/ directory.

Comment: what is written in Application.mk ? it may be that library is not being generated for your handset configuration ?

Comment: there isn't the Application.mk file. @Amit

Comment: can you change with jsting Java_com_example_FristJni_getStringFromJni JNIEXPORT jsting JNICALL Java_com_example_FristJni_getStringFromJni in the header and source file and see if it makes any difference

Comment: JNIEXPORT jsting JNICALL Java_com_example_FristJniActivity_getStringFromJni is the c++'s style. I tried to use C++, but it also doesn't work. @blackbelt

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html#faq_ULE has some things to check.  Make sure to check the logcat output a few lines above the failure to see if there are any dlopen() messages -- don't just look at the exception itself.

Comment: Is that a typo in `basic.c` with the return value being `jsting` instead of `jstring`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modify some values

**jni/Android.mk**

```
LOCAL_MODULE := libtestjni
```

Android.mk

```
LOCAL_JNI_SHARD_LIBRARIES := libtestjni
LOCAL_REQUIRED_MODULES := libtestjni
```

, and use the command "**adb install** ***.apk ".

Then it works well.

Answer (score 0):

UnsatisfiedLinkerror is solved by this.Build your .so file again by **ndk_build** 
Becuase every time u change the .c files ,you have to build the **.so** files